# Datasketches .whl Linux ARM64 for AWS Glue Job

Tags: python, aws-glue

I have some trouble to install python `datasketches==4.0.0` on Linux ARM64.

I receive the following error when I run `pip3 install datasketches==4.0.0`:

```
...

  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/tmp/pip-install-r9ab7pna/datasketches', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-r9ab7pna/datasketches/build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37', '-DWITH_PYTHON=True', '-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11', '-DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for datasketches
Failed to build datasketches
ERROR: Could not build wheels for datasketches which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

How can i generate a whl that will work on Linux  ARM64 of datasketches==4.0.0?

I would use this whl on ars glue job.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install datasketches on Ubuntu 22.04 AWS Graviton2 instance (arm64) with the commands below. I did get an error when trying to install pybind11 using pip.

```bash
sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install python-is-python3 -y
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
sudo apt install cmake -y
sudo apt install python3-pybind11 -y
pip install datasketches==4.0.0
```

Comment: I did the whl on a AWS AMI linux arm64 machine

`datasketches-4.0.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl`

but I have this error on glue No module named '_datasketches'

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue may be because you built the wheel against a different OS than what Glue is running behind the scenes.  When it comes to binary wheels, linux_aarch64.whl are compiled against a specific libc which will fail to load on OSes with incompatible libc's.  What you need to do is compile a `manylinux` wheel that uses a well defined build environment for compatible wheels on different OSes.

Example documentation on how to build a manylinux wheel: https://opensource.com/article/19/2/manylinux-python-wheels

Manylinux wheel project: https://github.com/pypa/manylinux

The steps are effectively, get the appropriate manylinux container (manylinux2014_aarch64 should be sufficient), start it, build your wheel, audit it and then you can use it.